# Why does mixture of echo and print commands in PHP have unexpected output?

Tags: php

Why does the following code:

```
echo print(3) . 2 . print(7) . 4 . 5;
```

Have this output:

```
7453211
```

Comment: What were you expecting and why are you doing it?

Comment: Order of precedence. In fact this is quite a nice demonstrator of same

Comment: You are echoing the result of calling `print()` at various points in this code.

Comment: The one non-obvious point here may be that `print(3) . 2` is actually `(print 3 . 2)`. `print` is not a real function and parentheses mean nothing to it.

Comment: The title is a bit misleading, since 7453211 _is_ the expected output.